# How update collections using Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I want to create the azure Function which is bind to cosmos DB.

- Whenever some insertion happens in "A" collection I want to update "B" collection.
- "B" collection has stored procedure which I want to call after the insertion in collection "A".

I am new to Azure and cosmos-DB.

Suggest me what need to be done to accomplish the requirement.

So far I have created Azure Function 
[image]

Also Updated the function.json with below code.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cdb-swm-dev-001_DOCUMENTDB",
      "databaseName": "admin",
      "collectionName": "aomsorders",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "admin",
      "collectionName": "aomsorders",
      "connection": "cdb-swm-dev-001_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "admin",
      "collectionName": "test",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connection": "cdb-swm-dev-001_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Also Updated the Integrate Part as below

[image]

Any Suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: What have you done so far to accomplish this yourself?

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: You want one Azure Function that is listening to a collection (using the Trigger) and then writes to a second collection (using Output Binding)?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta  yes Exactly.

Comment: I am seeing you are still using portal to write the functions. This Monday, Visual studio released new version 15.5 which makes writing function with CosmosDB very easy. See the screen cast here https://sarosh.wordpress.com/2017/12/06/peanut-butter-and-jelly-cosmos-db-and-azure-functions/

Answer (score 1):

I find your question not very specific, but broadly you have at least two options:

- Insert to both collections from the same Azure Function
- Insert to the collection 1 from the first Azure Function, then have a second Azure Function with [Cosmos DB trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb) listening to the changes of collection 1 and updating collection 2

I'm sure there are other options too.

Comment: I am curious to know about your 2nd option. Aren't triggers scoped to a particular collection only? How would this work in that scenario?

Comment: @GauravMantri Aren't you confusing Cosmos DB's own triggers and Azure Function triggered by Cosmos DB change feed? Function can do whatever it wants.

Comment: I was referring to Cosmos DB Triggers only. Aah...now that I have read your response properly, I understand what you're saying. This makes complete sense now to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an Azure Function that gets triggered by a CosmosDBTrigger and then it uses a DocumentDB Output Binding to write to a second collection:

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "databaseName": "your-database",
      "collectionName": "your-collection1",
      "connectionStringSetting": "name-of-connectionstring-setting-for-collection1",
      "leaseCollectionName": "your-lease-collection"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "docsToSave",
      "databaseName": "your-database2",
      "collectionName": "your-collection2",
      "connection": "name-of-connectionstring-setting-for-collection2",
      "createIfNotExists": false
    }
  ]
}
```

**run.csx (C#)**

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
public static async Task Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> input, IAsyncCollector<Document> docsToSave)
{
    foreach(var doc in input){
        // Do something here, process the document or do your compute
        // Here I am saving the same document to the second collection but you could send a new document created within the processing logic or send the same document modified by some logic
        await docsToSave.AddAsync(doc);
    }
}
```

**index.js (NodeJS)**

```
module.exports = function(context, input) {
    if(!!input && input.length > 0){
        context.bindings.docsToSave = [];
        for(var i = 0, len=input.length; i<len;i++){
            var doc = input[i];
            // Do something here with the doc or create a new one
            context.bindings.docsToSave.push(doc);
        }
    }
    context.done();
}
```