# I need to create the azure Function which is bind to cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

When some insertion happened in "A" collection I need to update the "B" collection.
"B" collection has stored procedure which I want to call after the insertion in collection "A".
I am new to Azure and cosmos-DB.

Suggest me what need to be done to accomplish the above requirement.

So far I have created Azure Function.

Also Updated the function.json with below code.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cdb-swm-dev-001_DOCUMENTDB",
      "databaseName": "admin",
      "collectionName": "aomsorders",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": true
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "admin",
      "collectionName": "aomsorders",
      "connection": "cdb-swm-dev-001_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "outputDocument",
      "databaseName": "admin",
      "collectionName": "test",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connection": "cdb-swm-dev-001_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Also Updated the Integrate Part.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too open question for Stack Overflow. You should try to come to solution yourself, and then describe the exact problem that you faced. My remark to your `function.json` is that you don't need a separate input binding: trigger is enough.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/47699043/5641598